# Links to Document are empty after publishing

Tags: umbraco

Can anyone help with the following issue please?

(Umbraco version 4.0.2.1)

After publishing the new site and its sub pages, the links to document are blank and the Alternative links are just "N/A" for every page pusblished including root. When I opened www.123.com in my browser, it would just show the old content from the old site instead of the new content from the new site.

(www.123.com is a dummy url)

The Content tree is as follows:

---

Content

-- New site (published and assigned to www.123.com)

```
 -- New sub folder #1

    -- New sub pages

 -- New sub folder #2

    -- New sub pages
```

-- Old site (unpublished and unassigned from www.123.com)

```
 -- Old sub pages
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "old site" visually listed before "new site" in the content pane? You may want to reorder if so.

You could also try rebuilding the Umbraco cache. Visit:

YOURDOMAIN/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true and click republish

(see http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/publishing-and-republishing for more info)